# Prove $\sqrt{-3+44a} \in N$ can't be a square root of a square of a natural number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, provability

Prove $\sqrt{-3+44a} \in N$ can't be a square root of a square of a natural number.

$$ 
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
a \in N
\\
d \in N
   \\
-3+44a = d^2
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*} 
$$

Comment: Gelerum, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very low-quality question.

Comment: Edit your question with your efforts

Comment: Forget about square roots and just show that $-3+44a$ cannot be a perfect square. Working mod $4$ will not help, since $-3$ is a square mod $4$. So, instead, try working mod $11$.

Comment: @Angelo what should i write if tried to solve regarding d, but it was a stupid idea, it is an infinite loop of solving x regarding y, y regarding z?... You could write some thoughts, but you only told me i have no solution, i knew it before you.

Comment: @gelerum, just read Lion Heart’s comment and do it.

Comment: $d$ has to be odd. Plug that in and both sides are divisible by 4. Divide by 4. The new equation asserts the existence of a multiple of $11$ that has the form $k^2+k+1$ for some integer $k$. Test all necessary values to rule them all out to conclude that this doesn't work.

Comment: That is doing it the hard way in terms of number of calculations. There's an easier way using some slightly more abstract concepts. Try the hard way and maybe someone will write up an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a square root of the square of a natural number (a perfect square) equal to the natural number itself, we need to prove that $\sqrt{-3+44a}$ cannot be a natural number. Thus, we need to prove that $44a-3$ cannot be a perfect square.

We can prove this by $44a-3 \equiv 8 \pmod{11}$. Since a perfect square modulo 11 equals to one of the set {0, 1, 4, 9, 5, 3}, $44a-3$ is not a perfect square. Therefore, $\sqrt{-3+44a}$ can't be a square root of a square of a natural number.

Comment: Thank you. But can you guide me why you chose 11 for modulo and why do you use this set? I don't know some theorem?

Comment: I choose 11 for modulo because it is the only number I can choose for this question. If I choose 2 or 4,  44a-3 modulo 2 or 4 equals to 1, which cannot prove this question.

Comment: I see that all squares modulo 11 are in the set. But i don't really understand why it is truth. I see that even squares of prime numbers modulo 11 are in this set. But why does the set of 6 numbers cover the infinity of natural numbers? And i still can't get if we choose modulo 2, the remainder of 44a-3 will be in the set for mod 2, then we can prove 44a-3 can be a perfect square. But if we choose mod 11 we prove it can't be a perfect square, We just choose modulo that we want depending whether we want to prove or refute.

Comment: The set of 6 numbers cover the infinity of natural numbers because 11 is less than 100 (10^2) and we only need to calculate what x^2(0<=x<=9) modulo 11 equals to. It is the same for modulo 2 and 4. We cannot prove that 44a-3 is a perfect square by its modulo is in the set for mod 2, because other natural numbers modulo 2 may also equal to 1 without being a perfect square. However, we can prove that 44a-3 is not a perfect square by proving that it is not included in the set for modulo 11 because the set contains all perfect squares modulo 11. Hope this helps!

Comment: No, i didn't understand. Especially, "The set of 6 numbers cover the infinity of natural numbers because 11 is less than 100 (10^2) and we only need to calculate what x^2(0<=x<=9) modulo 11 equals to". But i saw somewhere something with sets for modules, that's why i will accept this solution...

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it more clearly. Hope you can understand my solution!